# from dispatcher import dp ImportError: cannot import name ‘dp’ from ‘dispatcher’

Tags: python, database, aiogram

I'm writing code in Python, a bot for financial accounting, with a database, but it displays an error
How can I change the code so that it stops displaying the error?

---

```py
from aiogram import executor
from dispatcher import dp
import handlers

from db import BotDB
BotDB = BotDB('accountant.db')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```